# Swagger UI issue with camelCase

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am facing problem with the query parameters if they are in camelCase format.

for ex : http://localhost:9000/api/hello?personName=test

This format doesnt work with the Swagger UI. Swagger is not able to pickup any parameter defined in camelCase. It shows error "missing required params: presonName".

[image]

Hope this is clear now.

Adding one more screen shot with error

[image]

thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem. Saying 'not working for me' without giving details as to what happens and what you expect to happen won't allow people to help.

Comment: Question is still unclear, can't really help with it.

Comment: change my question, please have a look now

Comment: Just tested it, works fine for me using the current `master` version.

Comment: Hi Ron, which version are you refering to ? I just used 3.0.0 And with 3.1.0 , it dint work

Comment: The latest version is 2.1.2, so you didn't use 3.0.0 nor 3.1.0.

Comment: dint work either.... just downloaded from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/v2.1.2.zip and used the content from dist folder... but still the same issue. I just updated the question with error screenshot

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help without your full swagger definition or at least one that reproduces the issue as it doesn't happen to me when I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wierd but true. I ended up finding something which is a very rare case. As you can see in the screen shot, I was using nodeType as a parameter and to my surprise, the word nodeType is a reserved word in "document" object of html. and thats the reason it creates a problem. I just changed the nodeType to nodeTypeStr and it works fine for me. But still it will be good if Swagger developers take care of handling the reserved words.